# How to correctly allocate space in a two-dimensional array while avoiding memory corruption?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

**For an algorithm, I wanted to allocate space to a two-dimensional array every time it was needed, instead, I get this error**

```
`main.run: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top ==   initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted`
```

---

I've tried Valgrind witch outputs:

```
==2903== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2903== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2903== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2903== Command: ./main.run
==2903== 
==2903== Invalid write of size 4
==2903==    at 0x1087B7: main (main.c:18)
==2903==  Address 0x51d70e4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==2903==    at 0x4C2BBAF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2903==    by 0x108787: main (main.c:17)
==2903== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 12, hi = 368578837618884608.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==2903==    at 0x38083828: show_sched_status_wrk (m_libcassert.c:343)
==2903==    by 0x38083944: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:419)
==2903==    by 0x38083AD1: vgPlain_assert_fail (m_libcassert.c:485)
==2903==    by 0x38091882: get_bszB_as_is (m_mallocfree.c:301)
==2903==    by 0x38091882: get_bszB (m_mallocfree.c:311)
==2903==    by 0x38091882: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:1734)
==2903==    by 0x3804FAD4: vgMemCheck_new_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:350)
==2903==    by 0x3804FCA6: vgMemCheck_malloc (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:385)
==2903==    by 0x380D7B53: do_client_request (scheduler.c:1866)
==2903==    by 0x380D7B53: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1425)
==2903==    by 0x380E6416: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:103)
==2903==    by 0x380E6416: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:156)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 2903)
==2903==    at 0x4C2BBAF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2903==    by 0x108787: main (main.c:17)
```

---

This is the code that causes the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define cats 3
#define loops 30

int main() {
    int **a;
    int i,j;

    a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < cats; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < loops; j++) {
            a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
            a[i][j] = i + j;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < loops; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How is the error caused and how can it be avoided?

Is this type of memory allocation a bad practice?

Comment: The problem, as others indicate, is that you don't ask "how many?" as you need _cats_ rows of _loops_ elements. Why didn't you ask yourself this question?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this code is an example, something I forgot to mention in the question is that unlike the sample I cannot Know how much space I will need

Comment: I can hardly believe you... Then why would you think that `a[i][j]` would exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are different ways to allocate a 2D `int` matrix:

- You can allocate an array of arrays of `int`.
- You can allocate an array of pointers to arrays of `int` and allocate a different array of `int` for each of these pointers. This is what you tried but the allocation sizes are incorrect.

The *array of pointers to arrays of `int`* should have a size of `cats * sizeof(int *)`. and each array of `int` should be allocated in the outer loop with a size of `loops * sizeof(int)`, instead of in the inner loop at you did.

Furthermore, you should free these objects before exiting the program so Valgrind can see a clean plate.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define cats 3
#define loops 30

int main() {
    int **a;
    int i, j;

    a = malloc(cats * sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(loops * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < loops; j++) {
            a[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < loops; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cats; i++)
        free(a[i]);
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

This style of *indirect 2D matrix* is usually frowned upon because:

- it is more complicated and slower to allocate, especially if you want to avoid memory leaks upon partial allocation failure, which is not done here.
- it is usually less efficient to access, because the compiler generates 2 memory reads to read a value instead of a potential multiplication and a single read.
- it is more complicated to deallocate.

There are some advantages, none of which are needed here:

- it is possible to not allocate some lines
- it is possible to share identical lines (at the expense of complicating deallocation)
- lines can have different sizes, but it is not a matrix anymore
- lines can be swapped efficiently.

The other approach, which is considered the only real *2D matrix*, uses a single allocation and a somewhat less obvious type for the matrix pointer:

```
    int (*a)[loops] = malloc(sizeof(int) * loops * cats);
```

Which can be written:

```
    int (*a)[loops] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * cats);
```

Or possibly more readably:

```
    int (*a)[loops] = malloc(sizeof(int[cats][loops]));
```

`a` points to an array of `cats` arrays of `loops` `int`.

This approach was only possible in early versions of C if `loops` was a constant expression, as it is in your program, but this restriction was lifted in C99.

Here is a simplified version of your program with this approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define cats 3
#define loops 30

int main() {
    int (*a)[loops] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * loops);

    if (a != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < loops; j++)
                a[i][j] = i + j;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < loops; j++)
                printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        free(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny, me I am curious why the OP accepted your answer rather than mine (done almost 30 mins earlier), I am disappointed to be frank ... so we are probably two to be ^^

Answer (score 1):

several problems in your code

> ```
> a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));
> ```

must be

```
a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*cats); /* size for cats pointers rather than just 1 */
```

and

> ```
> for (i=0; i<cats; i++)
>    for (j=0; j<loops; j++) {
>        a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
>        a[i][j] = i+j;
>    }
> ```

must be

```
for (i=0; i<cats; i++) { /* '{' added */
    a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * loops); /* moved and loops int rather than 1 */
    for (j=0; j<loops; j++) {
        a[i][j] = i+j;
    }
} /* '}' added */
```

With these fix, compilation and execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==5795== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5795== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5795== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5795== Command: ./a.out
==5795== 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
==5795== 
==5795== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5795==     in use at exit: 372 bytes in 4 blocks
==5795==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 1 frees, 1,396 bytes allocated
==5795== 
==5795== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5795==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==5795==    indirectly lost: 360 bytes in 3 blocks
==5795==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5795==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5795==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5795== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5795== 
==5795== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5795== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
p
```

of course you have memory leaks

Comment: Hi bruno! Do you really run your SO samples on a raspberry pi? so cute!

Comment: @chqrlie yes at home I almost all the time use the raspberry now, I start the Dell very rarely. I got raspberry (and nano) to produce BoUML for them on user requests. A raspberry has all to work on, I use raspbian on it

Comment: The next step is to use the embedded OS in your flat panel screen. Some of them use linux just for the OSD...

Answer (score 0):

`a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));` allocates space for **one** pointer dynamically and returns a pointer to it. You can't access `a[i]` for any i > 0 because it will go out of bounds. To allocate space for several pointers you need to pass an appropriate size to `malloc`.

Either...

```
a = malloc(sizeof*a * cats);
```

... or...

```
a = malloc(sizeof (int*[cats]));
```

... will do. Alternatively, you can dispense with the jagged array, since all your extents are equal, and allocate the whole thing in a single block:

```
int (*a)[loops] = malloc(sizeof (int[cats][loops]));
```

Less allocations means less chances to get it wrong.